# Parallel transaction in SqlClient Connection - INSERT and SELECT

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, transactions, tree

This may be rare case, I'm in need of Insert some record (in more than one table - Assume 3)

Table 1 has primary key and rest of the tables have foreign key.

All records containing primary key and foreign key inserts in a time.

For that I've use `SqlTransaction` to maintain ACID property in my database.

Now, Let me describe my problem.

1. I need to insert a record into Table 1 (PK)
2. I insert one or more record(s) into Table 2 (FK to PK in Table 1)
3. I need to `SELECT` some data in Table3 & Table2 (with same connection)
4. Process data received in step 3 (some tree structure and node related process)
5. With processed tree nodes & FK data insert record into Table3 (FK to PK in Table 1)

For required result, all steps have to be done in order (1 to 5) without skipping, to maintain ACID property all these have to be happen within one single `SqlTransaction`.

The problem is on starting step 3, `InvalidOperationException` is thrown with message

> SqlConnection does not support parallel transaction.

How to bypass this error and complete upto 5?

Thanks in advance.

Ashok. RD.

Comment: You need to post some code to get any assistance with this...

Comment: The error is being thrown because you are trying to open a new transaction on a connection where there is already an open transaction.  You need to fix whatever is trying to start a new trans rather than use the existing one.

Comment: Alright all, I've make it myself. Thanks to all, Thanks to @JNK